# is "ng build --prod" equivalent to "ng build --aot --optimization --extractCss --extractLicenses --buildOptimizer"?

Tags: angular

i've defined build configurations into angular.json for my project, and i was wondering if i can replicate the default "ng build --prod" in a explicit way.
This is my configuration:

```
"release-prod": {
  "optimization": true,
  "outputHashing": "all",
  "sourceMap": false,
  "extractCss": true,
  "namedChunks": false,
  "aot": true,
  "extractLicenses": true,
  "vendorChunk": false,
  "buildOptimizer": true,
  "outputPath": "dist-release",
  "fileReplacements": [
    {
      "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
      "with": "src/environments/environment.release.prod.ts"
    }
  ]
}
```

does these options produce the same as "ng build --prod"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is (from the default ng new project):

```
       "production": {
          "fileReplacements": [
            {
              "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
              "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
            }
          ],
          "optimization": true,
          "outputHashing": "all",
          "sourceMap": false,
          "extractCss": true,
          "namedChunks": false,
          "aot": true,
          "extractLicenses": true,
          "vendorChunk": false,
          "buildOptimizer": true
        }
```